# Unable to remove whitespace using different methods

Tags: python-3.x, replace, split, strip, removing-whitespace

I am trying to remove whitespaces that are in file.txt from a list based on that file.

I tried strip() and replace(" ", ""), both did not work. I am trying to avoid adding libraries, it would be easy with regex, but I don't know why those methods are not working.

Here is a sample line from txt file ([Download sample here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m6kvv458w6dl2mp/testfile.txt?dl=0)):

```
10311,CANCELLED/NOT ASSIGNED                            ,                                 ,                                 ,                  ,  ,          ,20160817,HD,        ,     ,
```

The code I used:

```py
found_raw = list()
with open("file.txt", "r") as file_search:
    for line in file_search:
    if no in line:
        found_raw.append(line)

    for entry in found_raw:
        found = entry.split(",")
    for item in found:
        item.replace(" ", "")
```

I also tried with strip().

```
for item in found:
        item.strip()
```

The result was the same:

```
['222GY', '1142                          ', '3980115', '54561', '1990', '7', '                   ', 'DR STE 300
     ', '                                 ', 'KIRKLAND          ', '', '
    ', 'S', '033', 'US', '20161109', '20110418', '1T        ', '5', '5 ', 'V ',
'50364434', ' ', '19930206', '
', '                                                  ', '
                            ', '
  ', '                                                  ', '20200430', '00994891
', '                              ', '                    ', 'A1E91C    ', '\n']
```

Here is what I want:

```
['222GY', '1142', '3980115', '54561', '1990', '7', '', 'DR STE 300', '','KIRKLAND', '', '', 'S', '033', 'US', '20161109', '20110418', '1T', '5', '5 ', 'V ','50364434', ' ', '19930206', '', '', '', '', '', '20200430', '00994891', '', '', 'A1E91C', '\n']
```

Comment: Please post the actual file.txt you are working with. Also, can you use a library that should come with your Python installation like csv?

Comment: I think this is where you are going wrong: `item = item.replace(" ", "")`

Comment: File uploaded. I would like to avoid CSV.

Comment: I also did this ```print(found[2].isspace())``` and returned ```True```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think your code has some indentation problems (e.g. after `for line in file_search:`, there is no indentation).

Second, this will give you what you desire:

```
with open("sample.txt", "r") as file_search:
    f = file_search.read()
print([l.replace(" ", "") for l in f.split(",")])
```

output (based on your sample input line):

```
['10311', 'CANCELLED/NOTASSIGNED', '', '', '', '', '', '20160817', 'HD', '', '', '\n']
```

Comment: It works, thank you. But can you tell where do I have the error? I don't see any mistakes in my code.

Comment: @Sliwa, First, check for indentation errors. Second try to use `print` statements if your program is small to debug, also, I would assign `file_search` to some variable, before using it (it is a good practice I believe). Updated my code.